# How to add our own app in share intent in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can we add our own created app in share dialog box i.e share intent in Android?

Comment: [Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `intent-filter` for your activity

```
<activity android:name=".your_activity" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and read data from bundle of Intent.

```
 String mStringShareText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (mStringShareText != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
```

for more information please check [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define intent filter for sending data and handle that intent in your activity. For example:

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```